# How to assign field name dynamically in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have `Drupal 7` site. It has custom content type node which has 25+ fields of which 10 fields have very similar name.

In a scenario, I need to loop through n products & need to get the different fields values.

In order to avoid if-else chain, I am thinking to construct the field name dynamically in the following way.

```
function GetProduct($node,$a)
{
     $fieldName = "field_product_" . $a;
     print_r( $node->$fieldName[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] ); // not getting value

}
```

I am using **php v 5.5.12**

How to get the field value in this way?

Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just forgot braces :) Use `$node->{$fieldName}` instead of `$node->$fieldName`:

```
print_r( $node->{$fieldName}[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] ); // works
```

Comment: Yes,`{ }`were missed.. Thanks :)